# why is my validation in password not working when connected with html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a javascript page and connected it with html page. In the Javascript, i have created validation of the password and if there is a password mismatch then it will alert that there is a mismatch.

```
function validation()
{
    if(password==repassword){
        console.log(" ");
    }
    else{
        alert(" ");
    }
}
```

Above code is the javascript code and below is the html code.

**LogIn**

```
    <label for="username">First Name: </label>
    <input class="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="First name"><br>
    
    <label for="username">Last Name: </label>
    <input class="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Last name"><br>
    
    <label for="email">Email id: </label>
    <input class="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email id"><br>
    
    <label for="labeltext">Password: </label>
    <input class="password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"><br><br>
    
    <label for="labeltext">Re-Password: </label>
    <input class="Re-Password" type="password" id="repassword" placeholder="Re-Password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"><br><br>

    <button class="Submit" onclick="validation()">Submit</button>
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong in my code? Thank you!

Comment: please add the form code also to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a reference for each *element* in javascript:

```
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const repassword = document.getElementById('repassword');
```

Now your variables are not local and you can use them in your function:

```
function validation()
{
    if(password.value==repassword.value){
        console.log(" ");
    }
    else{
        alert(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is to check if the password matches the verify password value.
From your javascript codes, everything looks good but if it is not working, then there is a problem with your HTML elements IDs i.e password field id and verify password field id. Check if you are making a mistake in any of the code you are using to get the element values.

A little mistake like

```
var x = document.getElementById("txtpass").value;
```

Where as, in your HTML source, there is no such element with txtpass as id could cause your javascript codes to break.

I would advise you post the complete HTML and Javascript codes.

Better still, use your browser console to check for the runtime error that is depriving your code from running as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `name=password` in your password and `name=repassword` in your repassword tag like

```
<input class="password" name="password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"><br><br>
```